# Multiple try statement in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am using "replace" through a list of names in "try-except" in Python 2.7, if one fails then continues on to try the next.

```
names=('file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4','file5')
for name in names:
  try:
    file=do_something.replace('original_name',name)
  except:
    pass
```

"try" always replaces original_name with file5, which is the last one in names. How can I make "try" part to go through a list of names and replace with the correct one? Or any other ways to get it done? Thanks.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you make your code example completely runnable? As you've currently written it your question doesn't make sense. Nothing inside the loop references name or names so what you claim happens cannot be true.

Comment: What exceptions do you expect to get raised by `replace`? Note that it doesn't crash even if no replacement occurs. For example, `"A".replace("B", "C")` works just fine.

Comment: Hopefully my new code will be clearer. I got no trouble with the "except" part. How can I make "try" part to go through a list of names and replace with the correct one? Or any other ways to get it done? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how your (updated) code makes sense: you replace `original_name` once with the first string in `names`, and after that all replaces will fail. Further, when `replace()` can't replace a substring, it will just return the original string instead of raising an exception.

Comment: Still very unclear what you're trying to do I'm afraid.  The clearest thing would be to make it, as @Duncan says, runnable: include some real initial conditions, a real (minimal!) example of `do_something`,  and some `print` statements at the end that output the things you're interested in. Then say how the output differs from what you expected.

Comment: I don't think that `try`/`except` block is buying you anything, at least not based on my current understanding of what you are trying to do.  Can you explain your requirements a bit more (sample input and expected output would be preferred).

Comment: Correction to my comment (first sentence): it will replace `'original_name'` in `do_something` every time with `name` (or do nothing), and since the last `name` will be `'file5'`, that's what you'll end up with in the end. You could therefore equally well do `file = do_something.replace('original_name', 'file5'), without any of your other code; it gives the same result.

Comment: What I like to make "try" to replace original_name with file1 if it correct then use it. If not then goes on with file2, file3, file4, file5 to find the correct one.

Comment: OK, so look at your code carefully. Is `'original_name'` really supposed to be a string literal, or should it really be a variable?  Is `do_something` really a variable (one we haven't been introduced to) or should it be a function call of some kind?  Finally, imagine an exception is raised: where do you imagine it would be raised *from*?  Did you intend there to be some kind of code that *tests* whether the result of the replacement is acceptable or not?

Answer (score 0):

This might do something along the lines of what you want:

```
def try_substitutions( original_name,  substring_to_replace,  names ):

    for name in names:
        new_name = original_name.replace( substring_to_replace,  name )
        if name_is_acceptable( new_name ):
            return new_name

    raise ValueError( "none of the substitutions {0} worked with '{1}'".format( str( names ), original_name ) )
```

Here's an example:

```
def name_is_acceptable( f ):   # example: reject filenames that don't have the substring 'GOOD' in them
     return 'GOOD' in f


print( try_substitutions( '/var/tmp/XXX.log',  'XXX',  [ 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'UGLY' ] ) )
print( try_substitutions( '/var/tmp/XXX.log',  'XXX',  [ 'BAD', 'UGLY' ] ) )
```